# Java reflection load class from test package

Tags: java, gradle, reflection

I have this structure:

```
│   build.gradle
└───src
    ├───main
    │   └───java
    │          Main.java
    └───test
        └───java
               Test1.java
```

Main.java:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> testClass = Class.forName("test.Test1");
    }
}
```

In main method I want get metadata of `Test1` class, which place in test package. But, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Test1
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:377)
    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

How I can get access to classes in test package?

UPDATE:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The separation between "main" classes and "test" classes is done in a way that "test" classes have access to "main" classes but not the other way. The reason is that "main" classes are available to consumers of your library, but "test" classes are **not** available to consumers of your library. There should be no reason for your `Main` class to access the `Test1` class.

Comment: It's the question of setting of the (relative) CLASSPATH.

Comment: The purpose of classes available in the `src.test.java.*` is to test individually the functionnalities you implement in the `src.main.java.*`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this may work in Gradle (at lest version 3.0 [years old] or later).

```
Class<?> testClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .loadClass("test.Test1");
```

(I assume `Test1` is in a package `test` and not, as illustrated, in a default package.)

Of course, accessing test code from production code is a strange design choice.